# What is meant by "Find an explicit trivialization of $\mathbb{S}^{3}$?

Tags: manifolds

The problem is "Find an explicit trivialization of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^{3}$", but I am confused because aren't all trivialization's of a tangent bundle just $\Phi(v^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^{i}}|_{p})=(p,v^{1},...,v^{n})$?  How can you get any more explicit?

EDIT: How hard is it to find a global trivialization of $\mathbb{S}^{3}$?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell what your notation means.

But, what is meant by a trivialization of the tangent bundle $T\mathbb S^3$ is a diffeomorphism $F: T  \mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb R^3$ with the property that for each $p \in \mathbb S^3$, the function $F$ maps $T_p \mathbb{S}^3$ to $\{p\} \times \mathbb R^3$, and the composition 
$$T_p \mathbb{S}^3 \xrightarrow{F} \{p\} \times \mathbb R^3 \mapsto \mathbb R^3
$$ 
is a linear isomorphism.

The notation you have written does not have the appearance of such a function.

Comment: You are asked to find a _global_ trivialization. Since $S^3\not\cong \mathbb{R}^3$, you should not expect to find a global set of coordinates. So, such a global trivialization should _not_ depend on coordinate representations.

Comment: Is it hard to find an explicit global trivialization?